# start a function when a div showed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an div with some numbers that with js count from 0-x for show them

i want the js start when user scroll screen on this div

but it started when page loaded

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (i <= 30) {
        document.getElementById("sabeghe").innerHTML = i;
        i++;
    }
}, 0.00001);

var j = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (j <= 3200) {
        document.getElementById("moshtari").innerHTML = j;
        j++;
    }
}, 0.00001);

var k = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (k <= 4600) {
        document.getElementById("projhe").innerHTML = k;
        k++;
    }
}, 0.00001);

var l = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (l <= 29) {
        document.getElementById("govahiname").innerHTML = l;
        l++;
    }
}, 0.00001);
```

js code

```
<div class="container text-center d-inline" id="sumtxt">

<strong>بیش از <span id="sabeghe" onmouseover="count(0)">30</span> سال سابقه</strong>

<div class="pt-3 pb-3 mt-5">

<div class="col-4">
<span id="govahiname" onmouseover="count(3)">29</span>گواهینامه
</div>

<div class="col-4">
<span id="projhe" onmouseover="count(2)">4600</span>پروژه
</div>

<div class="col-4">
<span id="moshtari" onmouseover="count(1)">3200</span>مشتری
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

html code

please help me
i want to count function start when scroll arrived to this div

Comment: setInterval with a value of 0.00001 isn't realistic

Answer (score 0):

> You should put your **setInterval** into a function, and then call it when your Div is shown in the view.

```
function startCounter () {

   // Your intervals

}
```

> So you should calculate the target Div is in the view or no? You can use the **window scroll** event to calculate and check it during scrolling.
>
> Then you should get the Div box coordinates by using **getBoundingClientRect** that returns **top, bottom, left and right position** of it.

```
var sumtxt = document.getElementById('sumtxt'),
     sumtxtBound = sumtxt.getBoundingClientRect(),
     viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

> Finally, you can calculate your Div is shown or no? if it is true so you can call the **startCounter** function.
>
> Also you can add an **offset** to determine how much of your div is in the view to call **startCounter** function. I defined it as **offsetTop**.

```
if(sumtxtBound.top < (viewPortHeight + offsetTop)) {

    if(counterStarted == false) {
        counterStarted = true;
        startCounter();
    }

}
```

You can see it in this snippet

```js
var counterStarted = false;
var offsetTop = -100;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {

        var sumtxt = document.getElementById('sumtxt'),
        sumtxtBound = sumtxt.getBoundingClientRect(),
        viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if(sumtxtBound.top < (viewPortHeight + offsetTop)) {

        if(counterStarted == false) {
            counterStarted = true;
            startCounter();
        }

    }

});

function startCounter () {

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (i <= 30) {
            document.getElementById("sabeghe").innerHTML = i;
            i++;
        }
    }, 0.00001);

    var j = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (j <= 3200) {
            document.getElementById("moshtari").innerHTML = j;
            j++;
        }
    }, 0.00001);

    var k = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (k <= 4600) {
            document.getElementById("projhe").innerHTML = k;
            k++;
        }
    }, 0.00001);

    var l = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (l <= 29) {
            document.getElementById("govahiname").innerHTML = l;
            l++;
        }
    }, 0.00001);
    
}
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px">Scroll Down</h3>

<div class="container text-center d-inline" id="sumtxt" style="padding-bottom: 100px;">

    <strong>بیش از <span id="sabeghe">30</span> سال سابقه</strong>

    <div class="pt-3 pb-3 mt-5">

        <div class="col-4">
            <span id="govahiname">29</span>گواهینامه
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <span id="projhe">4600</span>پروژه
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <span id="moshtari">3200</span>مشتری
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```